# Sql Condition Operator in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please Correct my query to `Select` data.
  If there is an entry in `LeaveApply` Table having given date betwwn a `from date` and `to date` in the table, i should get the `pK` of table else `zero`.

please help

```
Select  A,
        B, 
ISNULL((select LeaveApply_Id from Tbl_Stud_Leave_Apply where Candidate_Id=120
and ('01/13/2014 12:00:00 AM' between Stud_LeaveFromDate and Stud_LeaveToDate)),0) As Leave from TableA where Condition.
```

Comment: As a side note, [don't use BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp values](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Heck, it's not safe to use it with anything other than an integer count, essentially (and I'd avoid it then for consistency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the isnull to the column, not to the whole query.

Try  the below

```
select ISNULL(LeaveApply_Id,0) AS ID from Tbl_Stud_Leave_Apply 
where Candidate_Id= @Candidate and (@date between Stud_LeaveFromDate and Stud_LeaveToDate)
```

In the above `@Candidate` and `@date` are dynamically passed to query.

Comment: Thanks.@Naveen Actually I need it as an inner Query. ie select a,b, c from table where some condition. The above query goes in place of a , b, or c

Comment: You can do this way for inner query also. If this helped you, accept this answer. If not, give full query.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you do the lookup across a lot of results, you should consider a set-based approach to the lookup, e.g.

```
SELECT 
   c.*,
   ISNULL(l.LeaveApply_Id, 0) AS IsLeave
FROM 
  Candidates c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Stud_Leave_Apply l
    on l.Candidate_Id=c.ID AND @Date between Stud_LeaveFromDate and Stud_LeaveToDate;
```